# How can I configure in IIS to get on app A when I write in browser address "a" and to get on app B when I write in browser address "b"?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis

Details:

Windows Server 2019

IIS version 10.0.17763.1

Application A: DNS aaa.aaa.aaa.com port 443

Application B: DNS bbb.bbb.bbb.com port 8888

Both applications hosted on the same server (same IP) and both with httpS protocol but as I wrote above, different ports binded.

Both applications are visible via browser when I connect to them with IP:443 or IP:8888.
Default site has only port 80 (http) binded.

Problem: When I write in browser address "bbb.bbb.bbb.com" I open site for application A.

Question: How can I configure in IIS rewrite/redirect/reverse proxy settings to get on application A when I write in browser address "aaa.aaa.aaa.com" and to get on application B when I write in browser address "bbb.bbb.bbb.com"?

I think one of the bigger problems in this situation is using port 443 for application A and that's why DNS for app A and DNS for app B route me always to address with default port 443 which is application A site.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't even follow the recommended approach to host multiple sites on IIS. With modern features like SNI support, just host all sites as they should be at port 80/443 and use different host names, and then everyone will be happy (like no irregular ports). You can read more from https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics#background

Comment: or use the reverse proxy feature

Comment: I wasn't the one who wrote and installed these 2 applications there. They did DNS for 2 applications and they told me "It must work. Do it.". About "reverse proxy" - I tried it but it doesn't work at all. When I edited binding for application B and changed fromn https to http my reverse proxy rule works fine and I get what I want (address aaa.aaa.aaa.com leads to app A, and address bbb.bbb.bbb.com leads to app B - in browser) but when I revert http to https and make almost the same rule for reverse proxy I get error (HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway) when I try to enter on bbb.bbb.bbb.com site.

Comment: This is a site to discuss specific server administration questions, not to teach you how to handle bad management or other challenges in your work environment. Keep in mind if you configure the sites like the recommended approach, then the good result achieved can be your bargaining chip.

Comment: and it looks for me that the backend does not work with https,so let nginx handle it, client to nginx via ssl, from nginx point of view, with HTTP which is fine usual

Comment: `They did DNS for 2 applications` what does that mean?

Comment: specialists said it can be done with IIS so I will not be able to request for paying for Nginx sub :/ They requested for DNSs for both applications and some admins prepared them and configured in some system.

Comment: Ask the specialists to teach you how to do it then.